# Configure and Manage array of Discord.js clients in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, discord.js

EDIT: Please ignore...  I've realised I've got discord wrong and it's all a moot point. A single discord client can handle any and all guilds that are connected to it.

Some time back I wrote a discord Bot in NodeJS.

It was very successful and I was asked to deploy it against another Discord server.

To expedite things I simply cloned it and edited a few settings and fired up a second instance on the server.

I have to do some changes to it to integrate with a different data source and the nature of the change make it practical to combine the 2 into one bot servicing 1 to n discord servers.

The relevant setup code at the moment looks like...

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});


client.on('message', msg => {
    // Handle the message
}

function setupDiscord(auth) {
    console.log("in setupDiscord");

    if (!issetup) {
        issetup = true;
        console.log("connecting to discord");

        client.login(auth.token).then(result => {
            console.log("Connected");
            isConnected = true;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("Error connecting");
            console.log(error.message);
        });

    }
    return (new Date).getTime();
}
```

At this point the single instance of the client is logged in.

But I now need an array of clients. (THIS IS PSEUDO CODE!!!)

```
var config = ['token1', 'token2', 'token3'];
const Discord = require('discord.js');

var clients = [];

config.forEach(function(token) {
    var client = new Discord.Client();

    client.on('ready', () => {
        console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    });

    client.on('message', msg => {
        // Handle the message
    }

    function setupDiscord(auth) {
        console.log("in setupDiscord");

        if (!issetup) {
            issetup = true;
            console.log("connecting to discord");

            client.login(auth.token).then(result => {
                console.log("Connected");
                isConnected = true;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("Error connecting");
                console.log(error.message);
            });

        }
        return (new Date).getTime();
    }

    client.setupDiscord(token);

    clients.push(client);
});
```

Am I on the right track or is this doomed to fail?

Note: I am going to try what I've put above and regardless of whether it works or not I would appreciate people comments on a better way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Creating multiple clients to work the same base but with different features depending the server seem is extremely inefficient...

Comment: By example would you suggest that microsoft have different code base for windows per user because different users will want different icon for their start menu?

It's irrelevant though as I've realised I've got discord wrong and it's all a moot point. A single discord client can handle any and all guilds that are connected to it.

Answer (score 0):

I realised I had gotten discord wrong and it's all a moot point.

A single discord client can handle any and all guilds that are connected to it.